# Best way to directly manipulate java-based backend objects from flex front-end?

Tags: java, apache-flex, architecture

I'm currently stuck between two options:

1) Store the object's information in the file.xml that is returned to my application at initialization to be displayed when the GUI is loaded and then perform asynchronous calls to my backend whenever the object is edited via the GUI (saving to the file.xml in the process).

-or-

2) Make the whole thing asynchronous so that when my custom object is brought up for editing by the end-user it queries the backend for the object, returns the xml to be displayed in the GUI, and then do another asynchronous call for if something was changed.

Either way I see many cons to both of these approaches. I really only need one representation of the object (on the backend) and would not like to manage the front-end version of the object as well as the conversion of my object to an xml representation and then breaking that out into another object on the flex front-end to be used  in datagrids.

Is there a better way to do this that allows me to only manage my backend java object and create the interface to it on the front-end without worrying about the asynchronous nature of it and multiple representations of the same object?

Answer (score 0):

You should look at Granite Data Services: http://www.graniteds.org If you are using Hibernate: it should be your first choice, as BlazeDS is not so advanced. Granite implements a great facade in Flex to access backend java objects with custom serialization in AMF, support for lazy-loading, an entity cache on the flex-side with bean validation. Globally, it is a top-down approach with generation of AS3 classes from your java classes.

If you need real-time features you can push data changes on flex client (Gravity module) and solve conflicts on the front side or implement conflict resolvers on the backend.

Still you will eventually have to deal with advanced conflicts (with some "deprecated" flex objects to work with on the server: you don't want to deal with that), a basic feature for instance is to add a version field and reject manipulation of such objects on the backend automatically (many ways to do that): you will have to implement a custom way for a flex client to update itself to the current changes implying that some work could be dropped (data lost) on the flex client.

If not so many people work on the same objects on your flex application, this will not happen a lot, like in a distributed VCS.

Depending on your real-time needs (what is the frequency of changes of your java object? This is the most important question), you can choose to "cache" changes in the flex side then updating the whole thing once (but you'll get troublesome conflicts if changes have happened) or you can check everytime the server-side (granite enables this) with less conflicts (and if one happens: it is simpler) but you'll generate probably more code to synchronize objects and more network traffic.